# Can you use "little" to modify an adjective?

Tags: grammaticality

For example, can you say, the toothpaste is little minty, or little fresh? Or, for example, that man is little tall?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use *little* as an adverb to modify an adjective in **some** cases.

It’s not particularly common, outside of a few stock phrases, to do so with an adjective in the positive, and none of the examples you give sound idiomatic. They’re (probably) grammatical, but I’d say they would normally only be used in a humoristic or sarcastic manner.

The most common collocation I can think of where *little* modifies an adjective is ***little known*** (also sometimes written as a compound, *little-known*).

Apart from this quite limited usage, there is a more widespread and productive construction where *little* is used to modify comparatives of adjectives:

> Politicians are little more than a bunch of thieves!

Of course, when used this way, *little* means ‘only a little bit’, so something which is little known is obscure, rare, recondite. It emphasises that it is almost not known at all.

In contrast, what you seem to be looking for in your example phrases is ***a little***, which is (among other things) an adverb that modifies adjectives and means ‘to a limited degree’. If the toothpaste is *a little minty*, it means that there is a bit of a minty flavour to it, enough to be noticeable. If it is *little minty* (although that’s an awkward phrasing), you’re implying that you were expecting it to be minty, perhaps because it has pictures of mint leaves and says “Extra minty!” on the packaging, but in reality, there’s almost no mintiness at all.

*Tall* is an interesting case, because you wouldn’t be very likely to say that someone is *a little tall* at all—even though it is perfectly logical notionally (nothing unusual about “He’s a little short”, “He’s a little fat”, or “He’s a little skinny”). You would instead say something like, “He’s fairly tall” or “He’s somewhat tall” or “He’s quite tall”.

Using *little* alone here makes it even odder. “He’s little tall” would mean that he is actually *short* (whereas “He’s a little tall”, while uncommon, would mean that he is slightly above average height), but it is something you’d only expect to hear by someone who’s deliberately using unusual phrasing for effect, probably humoristic understatement. It’s a bit similar to saying that someone is ‘vertically challenged’.

Comment: I agree with everything here. But I'd add that *little-known* is normally hyphenated if it comes *before* the modified noun, but not if it's *after* - *"A **little-known** man is **little known**"*. Which I think is something of a "fixed term", since *little* without ***a*** is a relatively uncommon/literary/dated usage today. But *a little = a bit = a tad = somewhat* remains fully current.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Adjectives modified by adverbs of degree are usually hyphenated when used attributively (“a fully-understood problem”, but “the problem is fully understood”); what I meant was that _little(-)known_ and _well(-)known_ are both sometimes found hyphenated even when used predicatively (“this problem is well-known”), which is a tendency limited to just a few fixed terms.

Comment: It's true both forms do occur in both positions (and in a case like this, I think "correct/incorrect" is a sterile debate). But whereas the hyphen is [*twice as likely in attributive usages*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+little-known%2Ca+little+known&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20little%20-%20known%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20little%20known%3B%2Cc0)...

Comment: ...it practically [*flatlines in predicative contexts*.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+little-known%2Cis+little+known&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cis%20little%20-%20known%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cis%20little%20known%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: As hinted at in the last paragraph, the adverb *slightly* will be serviceable to modify adjectives in many contexts.

Comment: It's idiomatic enough to say "I'm a little tall for this", though that might be regional, and it's short for "I'm a little _too_ tall for this". Compare it with, for example, "Aren't you a little old to be playing with action figures?"

Comment: @SpacePope I did consider that (but didn’t want to overly complicate matters). When no such comparison is implied, though, you wouldn’t use it. For example, if someone asks you if Person A would make a good polo player [where I presume being short is an advantage?], you could reply, “He’s a little tall, isn’t he?”. But if the question were how tall Person B is, you wouldn’t reply like that.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet A good point. The idiom doesn't stand on its own, only in a specific context.

Comment: @SpacePope I'm just over 6 feet, and I wouldn't bat an eye if someone said that I'm "a little tall" when describing me.

Comment: +1 Nice post. Like the discussion of *tall*. Was thinking that you could have *a little tall for that*. I wonder if *a little* has a slightly negative connotation?

Comment: Fun with the adverbial little: "It was a little bit sandwich."

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm sorry to bring this up once again, but I was watching an episode of grey's anatomy and one of the characters said to the other "You intimidate me a little.". My question is: Can I say that sentence without the article "a"? And what does it mean? If I can't use it that way how can I say that "You don't intimidade me much, you do, but it is so little that it is barely noticeable."?

Answer (score 5):

You would use "**a little**".

> It's a little cold today.

or

> Sorry, I'm a little late.

I'd be careful about using "a little tall", however.  It doesn't quite sound right due to the contradictory terms used.  Go with "quite tall" in that scenario.

Comment: So, you can use "a little" but not "little"? I want to say that it's not fresh enough, or that it's not minty enough.

Comment: @Pedro You wouldn’t use _a little_ for that; but you wouldn’t say “This toothpaste is little minty”, either, unless you wanted to sound unusual. You’d probably just say, “This toothpaste is barely minty at all” or “There’s hardly any minty flavour to this toothpaste”.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet ok, so is it only with adjectives that is sounds with or does it happen with nouns too? For example, "I have little money", is it weird too?

Comment: With nouns, it’s generally fine; at least, I can’t think of any instances where “I don’t have much _X_” sounds natural and “I have little _X_” doesn’t.

Comment: The adverb *scarcely* would serve in many contexts where you want to convey "not enough" of an attribute.

Comment: or *insufficiently*.

Comment: @Pedro Scarcely and insufficiently make sense for the toothpaste situation, but I would say that it is "hardly minty".

Comment: "A little tall" and "quite tall" have very different meanings. "A little tall" is a normal construction that I've heard any number of times, and means just tall enough to notice that the height is above average, like a 6 foot tall man. "Quite tall" would be well above average, like a 6'6" man.

Comment: These are good examples, because they both relate to something undesirable. The phrase "a little cold" and "a little late" are used to acknowledge but downplay the undesirable characteristic. Similarly, I would expect "a little tall" to be used in a sentence like "That bookcase is a little tall. I don't know if it will make my living room look cramped." That's not to say that "a little" is always used to downplay something undesirable, however.

Comment: Also, _I have little money_, while acceptable, is stilted. Usually one would say “I don’t have much money” or something like that.